# What is the no. of automorphism on U(6)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I tried with U(6)~U(2)×U(3)~Z1×Z2~Z2 and hence aut(U(6)) is isomorphic to Z2.
Is it the right way?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$U(6) =\{1,5 \} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Now $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_n)=U(n)$ and hence $ Aut((U(6))=Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2)=U(2)=\{1\}$.

Thus only $1$ automorphism is there.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two elements in $U(6)$ and note that automorphism maps identity to identity,  we map $1$ into itself. Since this map is in particular one to one, so we must map the other element to itself. Hence there is actually only one automorphism!